# Transforming Robinson to EPSG:3857 with GDAL

Tags: gdal

I’m trying to convert a full globe Robinson Projection to Mercator. For example, I use this [image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_map_projections#/media/File:Robinson_projection_SW.jpg).

First, I apply geo-tagging:

`gdal_translate -a_ullr -180 90 180 -90 -a_srs ESRI:54030 source.jpg source_tagged.tif`

and finally warp it to Mercator:

`gdalwarp -t_srs ESRI:54030 -s_srs EPSG:3857 source_tagged.tif target.tif`

The outcome is slightly stretched vertically but nowhere near proper Mercator. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of issues in your commands. The first is that -180 90 isn't in the top left corner pixel of global Robinson projection GeoTIFFs. The top left corner would be something like -338.2187147689 90, and the bottom right would be 338.2187147689 -90. However, you're also specifying your srs as ESRI:54030, so those bounds need to be in projected coordinates, not lat/lons. The command to generate a GeoTIFF from your image would be:

```
gdal_translate -a_ullr -17005833.3305252 8625154.47184994 17005833.3305252 -8625154.47184994 -a_srs ESRI:54030 source.jpg source_tagged.tif
```

Your second command has the -t_srs and -s_srs switched. Given that you're projecting to EPSG:3857, you'll also need to provide bounds since Mercator goes to infinity at the poles. So the updated command will look like:

```
gdalwarp -s_srs ESRI:54030 -t_srs EPSG:3857 -te -180 -81 180 81 -te_srs EPSG:4326 source_tagged.tif target.tif
```

I made the following projected image from your example using these commands (cropping the whitespace in the image prior to running them).
[image: Mercator map image generated by warping map in ESRI:54030]

Comment: Works great, thank you. I have two more questions, though. For the ```gdal_translate``` command, what exactly are the "projected coordinates"? Is this something that differs from projection to projection? Is there a way to calculate these from the lat/long?
For the ```gdalwarp``` command, you set the bounds to -81 / 81. I’d like to match a Google Maps Mercator projection. Are there defined bounds for that? Thanks!

Comment: projected coordinates are the x and y in the coordinate system. For most projections, you can just look them up on e.g. [epsg.io](https://epsg.io), but they aren't provided for ESRI:54030, I assume because it's not cylindrical. So I just grabbed the bounds using `cs2cs` at 180W/180E 0N for x and 0E 90N/90S for y. For [EPSG:3857](https://epsg.io/3857), the latitudes go from -85.06 to 85.06, so you can update the command with those values.